# Need help in enable configuration when compile Kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am using 3.10.x kernel tree. My kernel module needs config VIDEOBUF2.

That is defined in drivers/media/v4l2-core/Kconfig:

```
# Used by drivers that need Videobuf2 modules
config VIDEOBUF2_CORE
    select DMA_SHARED_BUFFER
    tristate
```

So I put 'CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y' in my Kernel config file and
compile. From the Kconfig it has CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE has no
dependency and I think adding CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y to my kernel
config should work. I am modify the right kernel config file since I
set other flags like CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y and that works.

The generated .config does not contain 'CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y'

and the compilation fails with  a bunch of

```
undefined reference to `vb2_buffer_done'
undefined reference to `vb2_buffer_done'
undefined reference to `vb2_buffer_done'
undefined reference to `vb2_buffer_done'
```

I really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: As you have stated ".config does not contain CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y'", obviously compilation will fail. Can you provide compilation steps you are following? there must be some point missing in those steps, otherwise .config should contain that label.

Comment: that also depends upon MEDIA_SUPPORT .please first enable that using menuconfig .search for for depend options on menuconfig

Comment: I have MEDIA_SUPPORT and I see that CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=y in the generated .config. I don't know how to use menuconfig. I am doing 'make myconfig' and make. I just need to add new configuration to myconfig.

Comment: *"I don't know how to use menuconfig."* -- Try `make menuconfig`.  Manual editing of .config files is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant directly comment on the subject as it requires 50 reputations to have this privilege. You can do : `make ARCH = target_architecture CROSS_COMPILE = toolchain defconfig_file`. This command execution will create a .config file in home directory of your kernel source. This file would contain default configuration for the peripherals on your target SOC ( I assume you have knowledge pertaining to defconfig files). Now if you wish to manipulate it and want to add your device support to it do : `make menuconfig` and you could add your device support by selecting configuration say like VIDEOBUF2_CORE in your case and then your kernel soure is ready to be compiled/cross-compiled. PS: Avoid editing .config file manually.