# Setting config when using 'make menuconfig'

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I create a new config with my Kconfig, like this:

```
config VIDEO_MY_DRIVER
    bool "my driver"
    default y
    depends on VIDEO_DEV && VIDEO_V4L2
    select V4L2_MEM2MEM_DEV
    ---help---
      This is a my driver
```

When I run 'make menuconfig' and when I search for 'CONFIG_VIDEO_MY_DRIVER', I See it.

```
 Symbol: VIDEO_MY_DRIVER [=n]                                                               
  │ Type  : boolean                                                                             
  │ Prompt: my driver                                                        │  
  │   Location:                                                                                 
  │     -> Device Drivers                                                                        
  │ (1)   -> Multimedia support (MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y])                                             
  │   Defined at drivers/media/platform/mydriver/Kconfig:5                                       
  │   Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y] && VIDEO_DEV [=n] && VIDEO_V4L2 [=n]                        
  │   Selects: V4L2_MEM2MEM_DEV [=n]                                                            
  │
```

But when I want to set it, I go to 'Device Drivers'-> 'Multimedia Support', I don't find the option to set it.

Can you please tell me if I make a mistake in my 'Kconfig' or where should I look for when I try to set it under 'Device Drivers'?

Comment: check in .config, you need CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=y, CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV and CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=n (or is not set) to make your option appear

Comment: I am told not to manually modify .config file. So should I add " CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=y, CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV and CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=n" these in my .config before I run "make menuconfig"?

Comment: You'd better modify them with `make menconfig`, but you can check in .config if it's ok, because those are requirements for yours to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link may help you get some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035150/need-help-in-enable-configuration-when-compile-kernel-module)

It seems to me that for that option to appear, first check whether the dependencies of your module are enabled like here in your case is `VIDEO_DEV` and `VIDEO_V4L2` . In your scenario it is still (=n) not included as part of your kernel source.